# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'segmentation_models'

Tags: deep-learning, machine-learning-model

i need to work with the segmentation model module, but even though I installed the module with the current version, it doesn't work what should I do

codes:

```
import os
import cv2
import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import albumentations as A
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import segmentation_models as sm

from keras import Sequential
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, CSVLogger

sm.set_framework('tf.keras')
sm.framework()

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
```

error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-72e520a0f699> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 import albumentations as A
      7 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 8 import segmentation_models as sm
      9 
     10 from keras import Sequential

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'segmentation_models'
```

Comment: codes are in google colab

Answer (score 0):

You are using this repo: https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models
So you need to install it first:

```
pip install -U segmentation-models
```

Comment: yes i know my question is i did what you suggestion in first line. I installed this:                               !pip install -U albumentations>=0.3.0 --user 
!pip install -U --pre segmentation-models --user  but after that when i called segmentation _models library like my first question it dos not work it says that module not found